# Suddenly customer_grid_flat table delete in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, table

I am using **Magento 2.2.6**. My site is working fine. But today morning I show `customer_grid_flat` table delete in my database.

Please, someone, let me know why it's doing.

Also in Admin side customer page display SQL error

Answer (score 0):

<s>You need to export this table from any other Magento of the same version. Then import it into your Magento's database.</s>

<s>After doing so, you need to truncate the table and then do the reindex by using the following command:</s>

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

**Update: There is no need to import the table manually. When we reindex using the above command, Magento auto creates the table and refills the data.**

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: When we doing reindex it's display table already existing but actually in db table is not display.

Comment: Can you post its screenshot: "When we doing reindex it's display table already existing"?

Comment: You can see here https://prnt.sc/n7fee4

Comment: Have you created the table manually?

Comment: Ya. Still it's not create

Comment: @SweetyMasmiya, I have updated my answer.